# How do I filter this URL?

Tags: php

I am not able to find a code to filter this in PHP..

I do have multiple urls for example :

```
www.google.com
www.twiter.com
www.facebook.com
www.youtube.com
www.techcrunch.com/webroot-brightcloud/
www.mashable.com/hello-how-are-you/
www.yahoo.com
www.msn.com
```

what I want is I need to filter domains with sub directories or pages. here in example techcrunch.com and mashable.com need to remove from final list as they do have sub pages.

The above is an example so any domains with sub pages or sub directories need to be remove from list.

How do we do it in PHP

Comment: You need to match the URLs with RegEx.

And what do you mean by "filter"? Block access to your website?

**EDIT:** I misunderstood the question. Seems Artefacto has the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_filter($arr, function ($el) { return strpos($el, "/") === false; });
```

Or for versions < PHP 5.3:

```
function sel($el) {
    return strpos($el, "/") === false;
}
$res = array_filter($arr, 'sel');
```

Answer (score 1):

If the mere existence of a forward slash is all you need to filter, then go with Artefacto's answer. If you need to be able to deal with less predictable formats, you can use [parse_url](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$url = 'www.techcrunch.com/?a=asd/zxc';
$urlInfo = parse_url("http://$url");
if (strlen(trim($urlInfo['path'], '/'))) {
    // remove from list
}
```